# date difference and add difference to new date

Tags: typescript

Using typescript.
I have date 1 string format and date 2 string format. Now need to calculate the difference between these two and then whatever result it comes add the difference to date 1 and display new date. Initial calculation must include date/month/year/hour/min/sec/mili seconds and also it should work in all time regions.

```
Example :
date 1 = "10/06/2021 10:10:05"
date 2 = "08/06/2021 11:10:05"

calculatedDate = date 1 - date 2
2 days = 10/06/2021 10:10:05 - 08/06/2021 11:10:05

date 1 = date 1 + 2 days = 12/06/2021 HH:MM:SS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the difference first and it might be negative based on the dates given. If you prefer to reduce the date from date1 in case date2 is the latest, remove the `Math.abs` in the below snippet. Rest should work perfectly as you intended.

```
var date1: Date = new Date("10/06/2021 10:10:05")
var date2: Date = new Date("08/06/2021 11:10:05")

var dateDifference = Math.abs(date1.valueOf() - date2.valueOf());

var newDate = new Date(date1.valueOf() + dateDifference);

console.log(newDate)
```

This will produce an output of `2021-12-06T03:40:05.000Z`. If you want it to be like `06/12/2021 9:10:05`, use the below snippet.

```
console.log(newDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit',year: 'numeric'}) + " " + newDate.toLocaleTimeString().substring(0, 7))
```

Comment: In line number 3 var dateDifference getting error The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362). If I assign type :any then it gives number like 16180000 an it sayd invalid date.

Comment: Added typescript code. Can you check now?